# Java EE 8. Не работает валидатор

Tags: java, java-ee, валидация, bean-validation

Не работает валидатор, т.е. при попытки записи в поле класса `setTitle(title)`, где `title = null` он даже не вызывается (см. логи ниже). Целый день сижу, уже всё прогуглил, нет ничего даже похожего на решение.

P.S.: Да, я знаю что есть уже готовый валидатор, но хочу на таком "простом" примере попробывать написать свой.

**Использую:**

- GlassFish 4
- Java EE 8
- Maven
- IntelliJ IDEA

**Book.java**

```
package bookstore.items;

import bookstore.validators.NotNull;

public class Book {
    @NotNull
    private String title;

    private int cost;

    private String author;

    private String code;

    public Book(String title, int cost, String author) {
        setTitle(title);
        setCost(cost);
        setAuthor(author);
    }
    /* Геттеры и сеттеры */
}
```

**NotNull.java**

```
package bookstore.validators;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotNullValidator.class)
public @interface NotNull {
    String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**NotNullValidator.java**

```
package bookstore.validators;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import bookstore.interceptors.Loggable;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class NotNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNull, Object> {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Loggable
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (object != null) {
            logger.info("Validator value : true");
            return true;
        }
        logger.info("Validator value : false");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**BookService.java**

```
package bookstore.services;

import bookstore.interceptors.Loggable;
import bookstore.items.Book;
import bookstore.items.numbergenerator.NumberGenerator;
import bookstore.items.numbergenerator.annotations.Issn;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class BookService {
    @Inject
    @Issn
    private NumberGenerator numberGenerator;

    @Loggable
    public Book addBook(String title, int cost, String author) {
        Book book = new Book(title, cost, author);
        book.setCode(numberGenerator.generateNumber());
        return book;
    }
}
```

**AddBookServlet.java**

```
public class AddBookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    private BookService bookService;

    @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

        books.add(bookService.addBook(null, 1, "TestAuthor1"));

        Writer writer = resp.getWriter();
        for (Book book : books) {
            writer.write(book.getTitle() + " " + book.getAuthor() + " " + book.getCost() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Лог исполнения:**

> ```
> 2018-06-17 16:39:16 INFO  Field:18 - Invoked: addBook
> 2018-06-17 16:39:16 INFO  Field:22 - Closed: addBook
> ```

Comment: Валидатор - это не какая-то автомагия, вам нужно будет самому создать и применить его.

Comment: @etki Так я же вроде и создал и применил `@NotNull`, в классе `Book` поле `title`. В книге Энтони Гонсалвеса дан этот пример, но он не работает

Comment: Разве то, что если применить валидатор к полю класса, не вынужнает методы изменяющие его валидировать новое значение?

Comment: Нет, вы сейчас как раз про магию, которой нет и никогда не будет. В условном спринге есть специальные процессоры, которые работают с кодом и вытаскивают `@Valid`, но по факту это уже совсем другой код, и в ванильной джаве у вас ничего такого нет.

Comment: @etki однако, если изменить метод `public Book addBook(@NotNull String title, int cost, String author)`, тогда валидатор отрабатывает как надо. Может чего-то не понимаю, но повторюсь в примере Энтони Гонсалвеса работает данный пример что дан в вопросе.

Comment: @KernelMrex потому что CDI-контейнер перед внедрением значений в аргументы методов делает их валидацию.

Comment: Похоже, что ваш бин не управляется контейнером.

Comment: @RomanC да, вы правы, спасибо) Подскажите тогда пожалуйста, как сделать бин `Book` управляемым бином, `@Managed` уже пробовал, не получается

Comment: Всё! До меня дошло как что должно быть, завтра оформлю ответ) Надо было просто валидатор написать и вручную валидировать. Я думал там автоматически всё работает, а оно не так. В общем всем спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы проверять валидность в JavaEE необходимо вызывать метод `validate`, у `Validator`, предварительно создав его экземпляр через `ValidatorFactory`:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
```

В моём случаем проблема решалась вот так:

**Book.java**

```
public class Book {
    @NotNull
    private String title;
    private int cost;
    @NotNull
    private String author;
    private String code;
    /* Геттеры и сеттеры */
}
```

**BookService.java**

```
public Book addBook(String title, int cost, String author) throws ConstraintViolationException {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setTitle(null);
    book.setCost(123);
    book.setAuthor(null);
    book.setCode(numberGenerator.generateNumber());
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Book>> violations = validator.validate(book);
    if (violations != null) {
        throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
    }
    return book;
}
```

Ну а затем всё вроде стало понятно :)